# I made an automatic wallpaper changing script that works on one computer but not another, unsure why

Tags: python, shell, gnome-3

My title might be a bit misleading, as I don't actually have access to the working computer and therefore I can't verify that it's ACTUALLY working on the other computer, but someone through IM told me it works on their computer, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the script, it uses only python 2.7.3 and uses bash wget and sets the background.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import os
from gi.repository import Gio

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://wallbase.cc/random/12/eqeq/1366x768/0.000/100/32")
page_source = response.read()
thlink_pos = page_source.find("ico-X")
address_start = (page_source.find("href=\"", thlink_pos) + 6)
address_end = page_source.find("\"", address_start + 1)

response = urllib2.urlopen(page_source[address_start:address_end])
page_source = response.read()

bigwall_pos = page_source.find("bigwall")
address_start = (page_source.find("src=\"", bigwall_pos) + 5)
address_end = page_source.find("\"", address_start + 1)

address = page_source[address_start:address_end]

slash_pos = address.rfind("/") + 1

pic_name = address[slash_pos:]

bashCommand = "wget " + page_source[address_start:address_end]
os.system(bashCommand)

print "Does my new image exists?", os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name)

settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background")
settings.set_string("picture-uri", "file://" + os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name)
```

For me, everything works, the HTML is parsed, the image is downloaded correctly, the image path is verified, but no image change. I use dual monitors, that's the only thing I can think of. I don't use any special configurations. I'm also using latest beta nvidia drivers, don't think that should matter. I also use compiz. Ubuntu 12.04 x86.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

That line also correctly returns the right wallpaper image.

Comment: Have you tried simply isolating those last two lines as a test on your machine? Can you open a python shell, and call them with a literal image path and see it change the wallpaper?

Comment: @jdi Indeed, from the python interpreter directly, it works. This is what I used:

`>>> from gi.repository import Gio {enter} >>> Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background").set_string("picture-uri", "file:///home/{me}/autowallpaperchanger/wallpaper-1813582.jpg")` and it worked beautifully. I also tried hard coding the path into the script instead of using os.getcwd() (like I did in the python interpreter) but that also did not work.

Comment: @jdi Does that script work on your machine? (if it's testable on yours, I think all you need is gnome3)

Comment: I tested it on an Ubuntu VM that is running a Gnome 2+ version and the operation has no effect.

Comment: @jdi I'm quite sure that gsettings requires gnome3+ but thank you for trying!